# Question about hint from an exercise from Stein's Complex Analysis. Finding uniform constant bounds for infinite products

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am having difficulty following the hint of this exercise from Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis. This is Exercise 4 of Chapter 5.

Let $t>0$ be given and fixed, and define $F(z)$ by 
$$F(z) = \Pi_{n=1}^\infty (1-e^{-2\pi nt} e^{2\pi iz}).$$

(a) Show that $|F(z)| \le Ae^{a|z|^2}$.

The following hint is basically the proof. However, I cannot fill in some details. First, the constants of this bound must be uniform over $z$, so in the first bound of the hint, we should have to be able to choose $N$ independent of $z$ to have $(\sum_{N+1}^\infty e^{-2\pi nt})e^{2\pi |z|} \le 1$. But I can't see how we can get this $N$ that works for all $z$.

Next, how does this bound over the sums give the bound for the product, i.e. $|F_2(z)| \le A$?

Finally, for the final bound on $F_1$, how do we get $2^N e^{2 \pi N |z|} \le e^{c' |z|^2}$?

I would greatly appreciate some help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authors write $N\approx c|z|!$ Thus there won't be one $N$ that works for all $z.$

Given $z,$ choose $N$ such that $|z|/t\le N\le |z|/t+1.$ Then

$$|F_2(z)| \le \prod_{n=N+1}^{\infty}(1+e^{-2\pi nt}e^{2\pi |z|})$$ $$ \le \exp \left ( \sum_{N+1}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi nt}e^{2\pi |z|}\right )$$ $$ = \exp \left( e^{-2\pi (N+1)t}e^{2\pi |z|}/(1-e^{-2\pi t})\right)\le \exp (1/(1-e^{-2\pi t})).$$

Thus we have a bound on $|F_2(z)|$ independent of $z.$

**Added later** For the other estimate, let's start with $|F_1(z)|\le 2^Ne^{2\pi N|z|}.$ Now

$$2^Ne^{2\pi N|z|} < e^Ne^{2\pi N|z|} \le e^{|z|+1}e^{2\pi (|z|+1)|z|},$$

where we have used $N\le |z|+1.$ The expression on the right has the form $e^{a+b|z|+c|z|^2},$ where $a,b,c$ are positive constants. This is not bounded above by $e^{c'|z|^2}$ for any $c'>0.$ The problem is with $|z|$ small, not $|z|$ large (the inequality falls apart when $|z|=0$). So they made a mistake in the hint there, but it's no problem. Remember, the ultimate aim is to show $|F_1(z)|\le Ae^{\alpha |z|^2}$ for some positive $A,\alpha.$ Writing $A=e^\beta,$ we want

$$e^{a+b|z|+c|z|^2}\le e^{\beta +\alpha |z|^2}$$

for some choice of $\alpha,\beta >0.$ That's easy: Let $\alpha = b+c,\beta =a+b+c.$ (Think about $|z|\le 1, |z|\ge 1$ separately.)

Comment: Okay this solves the bound for $F_2$. But I cannot really complete the proof with the hint on $F_1$. I was able to follow the hint but 
 the final inequality apparently only holds for large $|z|$ as explained here. How can we finish the proof? : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3611911/exercise-5-4-of-steins-complex-analysis-how-to-bound-2ne2-pi-nz-by-e

Comment: It's exactly the same idea. $$|F_1(z)| \le \prod_{n=1}^{N}(1+e^{-2\pi nt}e^{2\pi |z|})\dots $$

Comment: Yes so we get $|F_1(z)| \le \Pi_{i=1}^N (1+e^{2\pi |z|}) \le 2^N e^{2\pi N|z|}$. But I don't think we have a $c'$ that bounds $2^N e^{2\pi N |z|}$ by $e^{c' |z|^2}$ independent of $z$.

Comment: I'll get back to you on this. Been quite a while since I thought about this.

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: I think the sum shouldn't be there  before the third $\le$ sign for $F_2(z)$.  And I'm not sure how to get $e^{-2\pi (N+1)t} e^{2\pi |z|} \le 1$ from $|z| \le N$. We would need $t\ge 1$ to ensure that no? I think this may be where we could use $N = c|z|$ for large $c>0$ because then we would have $ct>1$.

Comment: You are right on both counts. The sum was a typo, now deleted. And you're right about $t$ in estimating $F_2;$ I was sloppy there. I will edit further.

Comment: I think it's OK now. Note the way $N$ is chosen now.