# Exercise 5.4 of Stein's Complex Analysis. How to bound $2^Ne^{2\pi N|z|}$ by $e^{c' |z|^2}$ uniformly in $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$. For large $c>0$, how do we find some $c'$ such that 
$$e^{2 \pi c|z|^2 + \log(2) c|z|} \le e^{c' |z|^2}$$ for all $z$?

[image]

[image]

This is part of a hint in Exercise 5.4(a) of Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis. We have $F_1(z) = \Pi_{n=1}^N (1-e^{-2\pi nt} e^{2\pi iz})$ for a fixed $t>0$. By choosing $N \approx c|z|$, the hint says we get, from 
$$|1-e^{-2\pi nt} e^{2\pi iz}| \le 1+e^{2\pi |z|} \le 2e^{2 \pi |z|},$$ $|F_1(z) | \le 2^N e^{2 \pi N |z|} \le e^{c'|z|^2}$.

Thus, if we take $N=c|z|$, we get $|F_1(z)| \le (2 e^{2\pi |z|})^N = 2^N e^{2\pi N|z|} \approx e^{2 \pi c|z|^2 + \log (2) c|z|}$. So it seems like we need some $c'$ such that 
$$e^{2 \pi c|z|^2 + \log(2) c|z|} \le e^{c' |z|^2}.$$

I am struggling with the case $|z| <1$. How can we bound all such $z$ by some multiple of $|z|^2$? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Your inequality is equivalent to $2 \pi c r^2 + \log(2) cr \le c' r^2$  or $2 \pi c r + \log(2) c \le c' r$ for all $r > 0$, and that  cannot hold for $r \to 0$.

Comment: @MartinR But it seems like we need this for the problem as it is given in the hint of this exercise. I have added the details.